# Trying to print a statement using 2 variables and text in between them to create a math table

Tags: ruby, variables

I am trying to make a tiny little math calculator by multiplying user input by values 1-12.

I would like my results to print in this format: ***'3 x 3 = 9', '3 x 4 = 12'*** and so on.

I feel like my loop should function correctly. But I am not understanding the syntax of the print statement to print the results. I built my print statement off one of my instructors formats for calling variables and then appending the string with text.

I couldn't get the math function working with user input, but I finally figured out that user input had a new line character, and was treated as a string rather than an integer. So I have made changes including the chomp function and converted the user's input to an integer for the math calculation in the loop.

I am receiving the following errors to the terminal and I am not quite understanding what this set is asking me to do (I also had unexpected , errors but I removed those so far).

```
calc.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
...t + firstvar + " x " + i.to_s "= " + mult "\n" #print the st...
                             ^
calc.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
... + " x " + i.to_s "= " + mult "\n" #print the string by call...
```

My instructor was putting commas after certain parts to I guess terminate that specific piece of the line to perform a new function and add it to the string?

Here is my code so far:

```
#!usr/bin/ruby

puts "+-------------------------+"
puts "|  Cheap Ruby Calculator  |" #Lame Banner
puts "+-------------------------+" 

puts " "
puts "Please enter your number so that I can multiply it from 0-10 and give you the results"
firstvar = gets #get user input
firstvar = firstvar.chomp #remove newline char from user input

puts "You entered " + firstvar + ". Let's run that through the cheap calculator." #reiterate the uselessness of this prog

i = 1 #define i to 1

while i < 13 do #while loop to print each iteration
  mult = + firstvar.to_i * i #math function set to mult
  print + firstvar + " x " + i.to_s "= " + mult "\n" #print the string by calling user var and build the 2x2 statement and loop it
  i+=1 #increment i by 1
end #end the loop
```

Please let me know what you guys think based on the error message and the sample code I provided. I would like to learn what the error messages are actually saying, while also fixing my code so it will run through the program. Once I have completed that section I plan on creating a way to sanitize the user input and either have them re-enter their number or exit the program in the event that it is not a number.

Comment: `firstvar + " x " + i.to_s "= " ` is missing the concatenation operator after the `to_s`. Canonical Ruby favors string interpolation, though. All this said, IMO you'd be better off writing an expression parser (or using an existing one).

Comment: I recommend using string interpolation, instead of writing `firstvar + " x " + i.to_s "= " + mult "\n"` you can write `"#{firstvar} x #{i} = #{mult}\n"`. It makes the code easier to read and so it is easier to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for the help. We haven't covered string interpolation yet in class, but this definitely makes it easier to read and understand. I am assuming the #{} is a string interpolation operator for calling the value contained in the specified variable. I feel like this should be one of the first things to learn in Ruby.